# Incorrect output from overloaded << operator c++

Tags: c++, class, c++11, constructor, operator-overloading

I have `Class NumDays` as shown:

```
Class NumDays
{
   private:
      double hours;

   public:
      NumDays() { hours = 0.0; }            //default constructor
      NumDays(double hr) { hr = hours; }    //initializing constructor  

   //Large class, nothing of importance, rest of class omitted

   //overloading << operator
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, NumDays a);
}
```

I have `NumDay.cpp`  that includes:

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream& out, NumDays a)
{
   // takes amount of hours, computes to work days

   int temp = a.hours / 8;

   //gives remainder of hours after full 8 hr workday.

   double hrs = a.hours - (temp * 8);

   //outputs 
   cout << fixed << setprecision(0);
   out << (a.hours / 8) << " Days, " << hrs << "hours";
    return out;
}
```

And I have `main.cpp` to include:

```
int main()
{
   // Initialized UDT object Declarations
   NumDays hoursWorked_John;       // Instantiate with Default Constructor
   NumDays hoursWorked_Sue(36.9);  // Instantiate with Initializing Cons      
   NumDays hoursUsed_Sue(4.5);     // Instantiate with Initializing Cons

   cout << "John's initial hours worked: " << hoursWorked_John << endl;
   hoursWorked_John.addHours(56.78);
   cout << "  John's final hours worked: " << hoursWorked_John << endl;

   cout << "Sue's initial hours worked: " << hoursWorked_Sue << endl;

   //rest of main omitted for sake of size
```

When I go to run this small section of the program, this is my console:

[image: Consle Output]

Any thoughts on why Sue's hours are so fantastically wrong, but John's are correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  NumDays(double hr) { hr = hours; }    //initializing constructor
```

Whoops.  Here you leave the member `hours` uninitialized and modify the temporary argument `hr`.  You seem to mean

```
  NumDays(double hr) { hours = hr; }
```

(or better yet:)

```
  NumDays(double hr) : hours(hr) {}
```

Comment: Such a silly error. Thank you friend :)

Comment: Was this an inappropriate question to ask? 

I was downvoted 3 times. The question is valid, the formatting is good. I couldn't find the error so I felt it was appropriate to bring it here...

Answer (score 2):

```
NumDays(double hr) { hr = hours; }
```

should be

```
NumDays(double hr) { hours = hr; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you print garbage values, because your operator `<<` calls the default [copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) of `NumDays` which does nothing.

```cpp
NumDays(const NumDays& other){
}
```

That means you don't print the objects that you have initialized before.

**Solution:**
Change your operator prototype as follows:

```cpp
/*  change NumDays a to const NumDays& a 
 *  a must not be modified by this operator (const).
 *  a must be passed by reference (NumDays&) to avoid duplications (copy constructor)
 */
ostream &operator<<(ostream& out,const NumDays & a)
{
   int days = a.hours/8.f;
   streamsize old_precision = out.precision(0);
   ios_base::fmtflags old_flags = out.flags();
   out <<fixed<< days << " Days, " << (a.hours - days*8.f)  << " hours";
   out.precision(old_precision);//restore old precision
   out.flags(old_flags);//restore old format flags
   return out;
}
```

Your operator `<<` prototype can only work if the [`copy constructor'](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) is overloaded like this:

```cpp
NumDays(const NumDays& other){
    hours = other.hours;
}
```

I think you don't need `double` precision `float` is enough

Tested with: `g++ (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2`